# MySQL where joined value is multiple ANDs

Tags: mysql, sql

Running into a seemingly simple JOIN problems here..

I have two tables, users and courses

```
| users.id | users.name |
| 1        | Joe        |
| 2        | Mary       |
| 3        | Mark       |
```

```
| courses.id | courses.name |
| 1          | History      |
| 2          | Math         |
| 3          | Science      |
| 4          | English      |
```

and another table that joins the two:

```
| users_id | courses_id |
| 1        | 1          |
| 1        | 2          |
| 1        | 3          |
| 2        | 1          |
```

I'm trying to find distinct user names who are in course 1 **and** course 2

It's possible a user is in other courses, too, but I only care that they're in 1 and 2 *at a minimum*

```
SELECT DISTINCT(users.name)
FROM users_courses
LEFT JOIN users ON users_courses.users_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN courses ON users_courses.courses_id = courses.id
WHERE courses.name = "History" AND courses.name = "Math"
AND courses.name NOT IN ("English")
```

I understand why this is returning an empty set (since no single joined row has History *and* Math - it only has one value per row.

How can I structure the query so that it returns "Joe" because he is in both courses?

**Update** - I'm hoping to avoid hard-coding the expected total count of courses for a given user, since they might be in other courses my search does not care about.

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function

Comment: As of now every single answer (except for maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/60354623/7032856 due to an error possibly) accounts for the requirement of the users needing to be _"in 1 and 2 at a minimum"_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join users to a query that returns the user ids that are in both courses:

```
select u.name
from users u 
inner join (
  select users_id
  from users_courses
  where courses_id in (1, 2)
  group by users_id
  having count(distinct courses_id) = 2
) c on c.users_id = u.id
```

You can omit distinct from the condition:

```
count(distinct courses_id) = 2
```

if there are no duplicates in users_courses.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9EX4LyKgNscpVt2FMZyYJM/0).

If you want to search by course names and not ids:

```
select u.name
from users u 
inner join (
  select uc.users_id
  from users_courses uc inner join courses c
  on c.id = uc.courses_id
  where c.name in ('History', 'Math')
  group by uc.users_id
  having count(distinct c.id) = 2
) c on c.users_id = u.id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9EX4LyKgNscpVt2FMZyYJM/2).
Results:

```
| name |
| ---- |
| Joe  |
```

Comment: Thanks - though, what if they're in additional courses other than the 2 I'm searching for?

Comment: If you want to search for 3 courses all you have to do is include them in the IN list and change to: `having count(...) = 3`

Comment: Less about searching for all 3 courses - still I want to search for 2 courses, these users might be in other ones in addition to that which I don't care about in my search.

Comment: My code works for that case too. Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9EX4LyKgNscpVt2FMZyYJM/4 for your edited data.

Comment: Thanks - that does work! What would need to be changed to also support `AND c.name NOT IN ("Science")` for example?

Comment: Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9EX4LyKgNscpVt2FMZyYJM/5

Comment: Or this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9EX4LyKgNscpVt2FMZyYJM/6

Answer (score 0):

I'd write:

```
SELECT MAX(u.name)
FROM users_courses uc
LEFT JOIN users u ON uc.users_id = u.id
WHERE uc.courses_id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY uc.users_id
HAVING COUNT(0) = 2
;
```

---

For more complex conditions (for example requiring the user to be in certain classes but also not in certain classes such as "Science") this should also work:

```
SELECT MAX(u.name)
FROM users_courses uc
LEFT JOIN users u ON uc.users_id = u.id
GROUP BY uc.users_id
HAVING (
  SUM(uc.courses_id = 1) = 1
  -- user enrolled exactly once in the course 2
  AND SUM(uc.courses_id = 2) = 1
  -- user enrolled in course 3, 0 times
  AND SUM(uc.courses_id = 3) = 0
)
;
```

Comment: @Akina Can you elaborate a bit more? How do you mean?

Comment: LEFT JOIN will give the users who have courses 1 and 2, plus the records from user-course pairs for which the user record is lost (is absent in users table). But OP needs usernames, i.e. existing users only. So you must use INNER JOIN, not LEFT.

Comment: @Akina I see, you're deriving existing users only from the fact that they require the name though, right? I don't think OP explicitly stated that, besides they themselves use left join in their query as well. So I have to disagree. It's a habit of mine to use left join when I only need the table for detail info though.

Comment: Why would you use `count(0)`?  It looks sooo awkward.  You can use `count(*)` or `count(1)` or `sum(1)`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just created a view with `count(*)` in it before and the db converted it to `count(0)`. I just inherited that ever since. Though if I hadn't seen that I'd go `COUNT(NULL)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in operator and use select to generate list of potential users_id attending the second course, to find matching ones in the first course. This is many times faster than using joins.

```
select distinct u.users_id, users.name
from users_courses u, users 
where u.users_id in (select distinct users_id from users_courses where courses_id = 2)
and u.courses_id = 1
and users.users_id = u.users_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost similar to what @Nae's solution.

```
select u.name from users u 
where exists 
  (select 1 
   from users_courses uc 
   where uc.course_id in (1, 2) 
   and uc.user_id = u.id 
   group by uc.user_id 
   having count(0) = 2);
```

Comment: Thanks - though, what if they're in additional courses other than the 2 I'm searching for?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is close.  Just use `GROUP BY` and a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT u.name
FROM users_courses uc JOIN
     users u
     ON uc.users_id = u.id JOIN
     courses c
     ON uc.courses_id = c.id
WHERE c.name IN ('History', 'Math')
GROUP BY u.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.name) = 2;
```

Notes:

- This assumes that users cannot have the same name.  You might want to use `GROUP BY u.id, u.name` to ensure that you are counting individual users.
- If users cannot take the same course multiple times, then use `COUNT(*) = 2` rather than `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.

Comment: Thanks - though, what if they're in additional courses but I'm still only checking for those 2?

Comment: @d-_-b . .  Just add them to the list and change the value of "2".